# how to center image over another image in tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

friends I have got a problem to center an image over another image and centering in tailwind css.

```
    <div className="w-1/6 h-11 relative text-center">
        <span className="absolute left-0 right-0 w-full h-full">
            <Image className="rounded-md" src="https://files.virgool.io/upload/users/785524/posts/sojszup8zfru/72bgkgkumdcq.jpeg" width="50" height="50" alt="video of" />
        </span>
        <span className="absolute">
            <Image src="/svg/play.svg" alt="play video" width="25" height="25" />
        </span>
    </div>
```

and my result is :

[image]

or if set top and left in play icon

```
       <span className="absolute left-1/2 top-1/2">
            <Image src="/svg/play.svg" alt="podcast icon" width="25" height="25" />
        </span>
```

the icon is on the bottom right

you see play icon is top left of the image and I want to be in the middle

thank you for your help

Comment: Can you share your styles?

Answer (score 0):

you may try this class `object-center` to the svg image

ref: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/object-position

or
add these classes to the parent div
flex-row content-center justify-center

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
 <div class="relative">
                      <img class="object-cover opacity-25" [src]="course.img_src" alt="Card cover image">
                      <div class="absolute inset-0 flex justify-center items-center z-10">  
                        <mat-icon svgIcon="heroicons_outline:lock-closed" class="icon-size-18"></mat-icon>
                      </div>
```